# Use keypad to enter in currency value in desired format

Tags: iphone, uilabel, currency

I want to have a screen that starts off with "$0.00" (or other symbol based on locale) that I can enter values into and it will update one at a time. (type 1234, returns $0.01, $0.12, $1.23, $12.34).
I know how to do this with the digits entered into a text field and with the click of a button change the formatting either in the text field or into a new label. What I want, though, is to  do it without the extra button tap and use a label, not a textField.

```
float moneyEarnedFloat = [revenueTextField.text floatValue]/100.0f;
NSNumber *moneyEarned = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:moneyEarnedFloat];
NSNumberFormatter *currencyFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[currencyFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];

revenueTextField.text = [currencyFormatter stringFromNumber:moneyEarned];
```

An example would be mint.com's Add Transaction screen.

Comment: i am looking exactly something like this.did u achieve this??..if yes,can u please tell me how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSNumberFormatter *currencyFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[currencyFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
int currencyScale = [currencyFormatter maximumFractionDigits];
```

TextFieldDidChange:

```
[mytextField addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidChange) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

Then do:

```
    - (void)textFieldDidChange {
myLabel.text = mytextField.text;
}
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how this changes anything. The code I posted above does what it is supposed to, I just don't know how to implement it into the .m file to make it happen real time, I guess.

Please correct me if I read your post incorrectly

Comment: oh use the textFieldDidChange delegate method

Comment: look at my edit. Also in order for it to happen in real time, this is the easiest way even though you want to use a UILabel.

Comment: sorry to keep up with the questions, but where exactly to I put the textFieldDidChange? Inside the method?

Comment: the method? in the .m. The one line, in the viewdidload or wherever you load the view.